# insert data into mysql syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the sql that I am trying to insert and I get a error.

```
   insert into  instruments (symbol,exchange,FullName,IPOYear,Sector,Industry)
 values('PIH','Nasdaq','1347 Property Insurance Holdings, Inc.','Finance','Property-Casualty Insurers','http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/pih')
```

here is my ddl and I don't find anything wrong with my sql.

```
CREATE TABLE `instruments` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `symbol` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `exchange` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `FullName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IPOYear` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Sector` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Industry` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LastUpdated` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `Sector` has more than 20 chars whereas you defined as `VARCHAR(20)`

Comment: for IPOYear, you are passing in a string of length more than of length 10. `IPOYear` VARCHAR(10)

Comment: your query works find could you please show us your code ?

Comment: your Sector defined length is 20, but 26.. set to `TEXT` type.

Comment: Saying "I get an error" isn't helpful. Include the error. Don't make people do extra work that's trivially avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sector VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL`
You limited `Sector` to 20 characters and inserted 26.
Make it like this `Sector VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL` and it should work